# How to record api calls to mock in SwaggerHub?

Tags: rest, mocking, swagger, swaggerhub

I want to mock api calls from my application, and host the mock, so my tests can work without calls to real api. There is a service called restbird which does exactly that, but it is far from ideal for me. If you want to collaborate you have to host the service by your self. Also it has some errors like not displaying history of calls, or when it sends server errors for no reason. I want a service more robust than this one.

The only service that I think might be a good fit is SwaggerHub, it seems robust, it has virtual servers, and overall it is very popular. But the only problem is that I cannot find a way to record api calls from my application. So **how can I record api calls for SwaggerHub?**

Comment: Do you mean SwaggerHub? Or something else? "Swagger" is a collective name for many tools, so there's no single tool called "Swagger".

Comment: @Helen you are right, edited question to refer to SwaggerHub

Answer (score 0):

There does not currently exist any functionality within SwaggerHub itself to record API calls made from the Swagger UI module within the tool. This is a limitation of the open-source Swagger UI tool.

What I can recommend is you use the Swagger Inspector tool. The Swagger Inspector can be used to make API calls from a client, save both the request and the response, and even generate an OpenAPI file for you based off the request/responses. If you create an account and sign in, you can even save your API calls to a `collection` to use later.

Swagger Inspector: https://inspector.swagger.io/builder

Answer (score 0):

It may also be worth considering using ReadyAPI's Virtualization module to handle this use case. With ReadyAPI Virtualization you can record transactions from a browser, build mock services from the recorded transaction or an existing API definition, and then host the mock service using VirtServer.

ReadyAPI is a part of SmartBears API lifecycle products, so there are integrations between the two tools. For instance, you can port APIs from Swaggerhub into ReadyAPI directly and you can use mock services built in ReadyAPI to do dynamic mocking in Swaggerhub.

You can find more information about ReadyAPI Virtualization here: https://smartbear.com/product/ready-api/api-virtualization/

I realise this is a very late response to this thread, but hopefully this information comes in handy.